# Two iPhone Simulators at the same time?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

Is it possible to run the iphone app in two iphone simulator at the same time?
If Yes Let me know?Please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896487/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-multiple-iphones-using-xcode-iphone-sim

Comment: Easier to just use 1 simulator + 1 device

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is. Download the script [here](http://coderebel.com/2010/08/31/iphone_simulator)
and then run it before you open xcode in each users account. It will open the simulator in such a way that for every user you can run a simulator. Also, running multiple instances of xcode and debugging on multiple devices under the *same* user seems to work fine for me at the moment (XCode 4, ios 4.3.3) however I still havent managed to find a way to open more than one simulator for the same user though.