# how can I run multiple ios simulators to test p2p

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, ios-simulator, p2p

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to run multiple iOS Simulators at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835063/is-there-a-way-to-run-multiple-ios-simulators-at-once)

I'm trying to develop an app that uses the gamekit to communicate between 2 devices using bluetooth. I was wondering if there is a way to test this using just the ios simulators? Is there a way to use a virtual machine to run multiple instances of the simulator at once?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835063/is-there-a-way-to-run-multiple-ios-simulators-at-once

Comment: Yes, there is a script that allows you to do just that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334527/two-iphone-simulators-at-the-same-time/6324670#6324670

Comment: so i read the post and downloaded and installed the script but i'm wondering whether i have to create a new user account to run two simulators simultaneously?

Comment: so i set up the server and ran the script but every time i try to open two instances of the simulator i still can't.... is there anything i still need to install or any settings i need to change so that i can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to run into trouble with bluetooth in the simulators.

Running your app on two separate simulators isn't that hard in itself.

You might have to use a physical iOS device and connect it to your mac via bluetooth to the simulator.