# Run multiple iOS Simulator.app using terminal command 'open -n -a "iOS Simulator"'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I understand that some people will want to link to this question:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896487/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-multiple-iphones-using-xcode-iphone-sim)
[And Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334527/two-iphone-simulators-at-the-same-time)

A user can launch multiple instances of an application by issuing the following terminal.app command:

```
open -n -a "APPLICATION NAME"
```

When I issue:

```
open -n -a "iPhone Simulator"
```

I get another instance of the iOS Simulator. But the kicker is that it is just a white screen on iPad and literally no screen on iPhone. The Simulators will also be very sluggish to response, often bringing up our friendly beach ball.

Does anyone know of a way to get these additional instances of the Simulator to cooperate?

screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but it's not possible. Running the stated terminal command results in a "Only one iOS Simulator can run at a time" error.