# Where are apps stored in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode5.1

I'm working through Big Nerd Ranch's iOS book, 4th Edition. I ran into [Core Data; Cocoa error 134100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517129/core-data-cocoa-error-134100). I need to delete files from the local hard drive that the simulator references. I'm unable to find the directory where the files I need to delete are located.

Any assistance with this maddening task would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to delete the app from the simulator? run the sim, and delete the same way you would on a device: hold down until icons shake, and tap x

Comment: I've tried that. The error I'm getting is deeper than that. I need to nuke a file that's somewhere on my local hard drive--I just don't know where to look for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Simulator location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567798/iphone-simulator-location)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to see the file system on the iOS simulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480607/is-there-any-way-to-see-the-file-system-on-the-ios-simulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulator apps are kept in the user’s Application Support directory:

`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/iOSVersionNumber/Applications/magicString`
Where `iOSVersionNumber` is something like `7.1` or `7.1-64` and `magicString` is a GUID in a form similar to: `7DBA2C5B-51CB-4229-8AC2-B0BEFBA947F0`.

To access, open a Finder window and then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and enter: `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator`, then drill down as necessary.

An example from my Mac:
`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/75BA5125-9D4A-4090-9DBD-6B630CD5971E/Comics.app`

Comment: @Zev +1 for the "<kbd>" Fu, I had no idea!

Comment: I just wish it were easier to type. Would it kill them to make it, like, \this\ or something? Or even `<key>` would be easier than `<kbd>`.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up displaying hidden files from the command line, relaunching finder, and nuking the **** out of the simulator app directory. That fixed it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to delete the app from the Simulator: just hit the Home button (Cmd+Shift+H) and then click and hold the app icon - then you can delete it.
When it is done - build your app again.

Answer (score 0):

The apps are installed in the simulator at this path:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications
```

You may remove an application or all of the data of the application from this path

Comment: Actually: ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/iOSVersionNumber/Applications/magicString To access open a finder window and then Shift-Command-G and enter: "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator", then drill down as necessary.