# IOS app's location in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I developed an iOS APP hello.app by Xcode 7.0.1. The APP is installed to iOS simulator automatically and runs well by clicking start button in the Xcode. Here are my questions:

1. Where (folder and path) is the app installed to?
2. How can I get the hello.app or hello.app.zip for the simulator?
3. How can I install the app to the simulator manually once I get the app?
4. How can I get the hello.app or hello.app.zip for iPhone 6?

Thanks!

Comment: @ChintaN: Do you vote -1? Why? What do you edit in this post?

Comment: i did not downvote and i edit your post to read better.

Comment: To the one who down-vote it, could you let me know why you do so? Please add your comments.

Comment: Answer to your first question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25996787/590485

        In Devices folder you'll find a "device_set.plist" file. There you can find the desired simulator id. @user1443721

Comment: Once reason this may be downvoted is because a good Stack Overflow question should only ask one thing. You are asking several things in this question currently.

Answer (score 2):

To answer #1 and #2 (I'm not sure the difference in those questions) for iOS 11.3 simulator (Xcode 9.3):

First run `instruments -s devices` to get the simulator's Device ID.

Then in Finder go to `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[DeviceID]/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/[AppUUID]/[Application.app]`.

Note you can confirm you're in the right DeviceID folder by opening `device.plist` in that [DeviceID] folder and looking at `name`.

You can confirm you're in the right [AppUUID] folder by right clicking on [Application.app], click Show Package Contents, Open Info.plist, find the value of `CFBundleDisplayName`.

Answer (score 0):

Where (folder and path) is the app installed to?

Your app is installed in simulator , if you want where it is present right click on project show in finder you will get the path.

How can I get the hello.app or hello.app.zip for the simulator?

You will not get Zip from simulator. You need to zip the project by show in finder You can find your project their you can compress.

How can I install the app to the simulator manually once I get the app?

Once you run it will automatically installed in your simulator, you no need to install again.

How can I get the hello.app or hello.app.zip for iPhone 6?

If want app iOS device (iPhone 6) means you need developer certificate(cer) & provisioning profile so that it can be installed in your device.

Comment: Uma answer 1: it shows all the source files such as .h and .m, but not the   Hello.app.

Comment: Uma answer 2: We need to zip all files under hello.app, right? However, there is no hello.app in the folder you suggest.

Comment: Uma answer 3: I know this answer. However, is there any other way to do it if I need to install the app to another laptop's iOS Simulator, or if I have removed the app from my iOS Simulator?

Comment: Uma answer 4: So we will have 2 different versions of hello.app, one for Simulator and another for real iPhone device. How can I figure out which version it is if I get a hello.app downloaded from Internet or emailed from other persons?