# Is it possible to test an app using Bluetooth in the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios4, bluetooth, ios-simulator

The documentation does not say how many instances can run. Also it does not say if it does/does not support bluetooth
https://web.archive.org/web/20110510000057/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/125-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html

I just read the following and found out that it is not possible to have multiple iOS simulator instances running:
[Is there a way to run multiple iOS Simulators at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835063/is-there-a-way-to-run-multiple-ios-simulators-at-once)

I wondered if the simulator supports bluetooth at all. Do I need multiple physical devices to test bluetooth?

Can I get away with testing bluetooth by installing my app on one physical device and communicate to another app hosted in the iOS Simulator?

What is the best way to test iPhone Apps that require Bluetooth?

---

Update...

iPhone running 4.3.3 - Bluetooth is on

Mac OS 10.6.7 - Bluetooth is on and discoverable. Under advance.

Neither my home made app or the GKRocket demo app that ships with the iOS 4 SDK will show the other device from within the app.

Both will discover the other app in the network settings; however, not within the app. I don't know if this is a problem with config or the iOS simulator at this point.

Comment: Newer doc explicitly says that [Bluetooth is not supported in Simulator](https://help.apple.com/simulator/mac/current/#/devb0244142d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what kind of bluetooth testing you're hoping to do, but I can tell you for certain that it works for creating a GameKit session between the simulator and an iPhone - I use that quite frequently to test one of my apps. You can only have one instance of the simulator running at a time, so you can't test communication between 2 instances of the simulator on the same machine.

Comment: Yes, I'm using GameKit right now. So that is good news. It will make it easier to deploy to only one iPhone instead of 2. I haven't actually bundled and app for deployment on a device yet, so I need to get over that hurdle to test it. I'll let you know if it works when I get the app on my device. I can't play with it for a day, so I'll be back to check the answer when I get it going.

Comment: Ok, I have my app deployed on the phone. But I can not tell if Bluetooth is working because they are not connecting.

Comment: I updated the post - i have the app deployed; however, it is not connecting

Comment: I have not been able to connect to the iOS simulator; however, I was able to install my app on a second iphone and it runs just fine. It would make life a lot easier if I could get the iOS simulator to work.

Comment: @vesselhead, try switching which is the host and which is the client.

Comment: Interesting... right now I have been using GKSessionModePeer. Let's see if that makes things work. Perhaps there is a security setting for incoming versus outbound connection. Any ideas on which should be the server... I'm guessing the laptop. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: You comment spurred me to look at the network settings again. I went into the Advanced Bluetooth settings on the Mac and made sure that a bluetooth connection could be made to the computer. That made it work. Now I just need to understand more about the PAN networking. [link](http://i136.photobucket.com/albums/q182/silkcorba/Screenshot2011-06-28at52056PM.png)

Answer (score 3):

of course you can you should have Le Bluetooth USB adapter even if you have a built in Bluetooth

check this link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2295/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the Core Bluetooth presentation at the WWDC 2013, Apple
is dropping iOS simulator support for Core Bluetooth:
http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/703xcx2xljtlq481grxurla4/703/703-HD.mov?dl=1
(announcement is ca. 7:28 into the talk).