# Can't two user accounts use iOS Simulator at a time in Mac PC?

Tags: ios, macos, ios-simulator

I have created two user accounts in Mac system. Using VMWare one person is accessing the system and the other is directly working on Mac PC. When they both try to use iOS simulator it is showing the below alert message:

```
"You can't open the application "iOS Simulator" because someone else is using it. Ask the other user to quit the application, and then try again."
```

Can't two users use iOS Simulator at a time in Mac PC? If so can you guide me how to set this up.

Comment: no you cant.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5835626/1042240

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant have two Simulators running at the same time, but You can run a device and simulator simultaneously, each having its own debugger. You can similarly run many devices simultaneously, the problem is only with the simulator that supports only a single instance.

but there is a workaround have a look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896487/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-multiple-iphones-using-xcode-iphone-sim), Suggests you can achieve it by have Two users,

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Download the script [here](http://www.coderebel.com/2010/08/31/iphone_simulator) and then run it before you open xcode in each users account. It will open the simulator in such a way that for every user you can run a simulator. Also, running multiple instances of xcode and debugging on multiple devices under the same user seems to work fine for me at the moment (XCode 4, ios 4.3.3) however I still havent managed to find a way to open more than one simulator for the same user though.