# How to debug two applications at the same time in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I want to know is there any way i can debug two applications with two different instances of Xcode.

What i am trying to debug is a application trying to invoke my iphone app via a custom URL scheme.

I want to see both application logs at the same time.Is it possible?

I am debugging on the device not on simulator.

Please point to any proven solution.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this stack question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896487/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-multiple-iphones-using-xcode-iphone-sim

Comment: I already had gone through that solution.but that solution is for running multiple simulator instances.my question is on simultaneous debugging of two applications on the same device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look at the device logger?

Comment: Thanks for the response.I tried looking into it, it is very large and also i only find some part of my log.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can view two targets's output like that, but you can also compile from different versions of Xcode as well (watch it though cause you cannot use the simulator at the same time)