# Can I run an iPhone and iPad simulator at the same time

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to set up a continuous integration environment for an app we're developing. I can automate deployment and testing of the app using the iOS simulator in Xcode but only using a single simulated device at a time. Is there a way I can have an iPhone *and* iPad simulator running simultaneously?

Obviously I can create another build slave and run separate instances of the simulator on each but I'd like to avoid having to buy more hardware if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to simulate multiple iphones using xcode/iphone sim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896487/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-multiple-iphones-using-xcode-iphone-sim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of running a Jenkins build the best solution has turned out to be using *ios-sim* to launch and stop the simulator. It accepts a command line argument to determine which device to simulate. Because it also stops the simulator at the end of the job I don't have to use multiple slaves.

Answer (score 0):

Nope You cant.See the purpose.You can execute any one at a time even if you have two or more,so why provide multiple simulators?

Comment: Why? Because I'd like to run automated tests against both simulated devices without having to automate starting up and shutting down the simulators themselves which would add a whole layer of complexity if trying to do it on an OSX Jenkins slave.