# How can I debug multi-player game using Firebase and Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am working on writing a simple two player game using Swift and handling the backend using Firebase.

I am not sure how I can simulate the two players to see if the various pieces of the code are working as intended? To my limited knowledge, I can't initiate the device simulator as two different instances? How is this typically handled - specifically for Swift?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896487/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-multiple-iphones-using-xcode-iphone-sim ?

Comment: Long overdue Thx Frank :)